# Union of spanning forest is also spanning forest

Tags: graph-theory

We have one graph $G$ and we divided its edges on two graphs $A$ and $B$ (both of them have all nodes of graph $G$). Now, we compute spanning forest of each of new graphs.

Is it true that for every $F_A \in SpanningForest(A)$, $F_B \in SpanningForest(B)$, there exists $F \subseteq F_A \cup F_B$ such as $F \in SpanningForest(G)$?

Comment: What are $A$ and $B$?

Comment: Whoever edited this, the two graphs $A$ and $B$ should be vertex distinct isnt it?

Answer (score 0):

Let $G_2=(V_1,E_1)$ and $G_2=(V_2,E_2)$ be graphs  on distinct vertex sets $V_1$ and $V_2$ with spanning forests $F_{G_1}=(V_1,\tilde{E_1})$ and $F_{G_2}=(V_2,\tilde{E_2})$ respectively (so that $\tilde{E_1}\subseteq E_1$ and $\tilde{E_2}\subseteq E_2$). Consider

$$F_{G}=F_{G_1}\cup F_{G_1}=(V_1\cup V_2, \tilde{E_1}\cup \tilde{E_2})$$

which is a subgraph of $G = G_1+G_2 = (V_1\cup V_2,E_1\cup E_2)$. Trivially it holds $F_G \subseteq F_{G_1}\cup F_{G_2}$. Since $F_{G_1}$ and $F_{G_2}$ are spanning forests of $G_1$ and $G_2$ respectively, their union $F_{G}$ is a spanning forest of $G=G_1\cup G_2$. This is because since there are no edges connecting $V_1$ and $V_2$ the connected components of $G$ are just the connected components of $G_1$ and the connected components of $G_2$ together. Since $F_{G_1}$ and $F_{G_2}$ are spanning forests on $G_1$ and $G_2$ respectively, $F_G$ contains a spanning tree on every connected component (and no further edges) by definition.

Comment: Remarks: I assumed that by $A$ and $B$ you meant graphs, which I denoted by $G_1$ and $G_2$. As so often in graph theory, things are easily visible, but it is tedious to write them down formally. My answer is hence not that exact, but I hope it helps you to see that this question is somewhat trivial: If you build spanning trees on each component of one graph, and spanning trees on each component of another graph (with distinct vertices), then all these spanning trees together of course build a spanning forest of the union of the two graphs.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much. Yes, if you assume that these graphs are vertex distinct it is trivial. However here, we have 2 graphs: $G_1$ and $G_2$, which have the same set of vertex (they have all nodes of graph G), but they have different set of edges:

$G_1 = (V, E_1)$

$G_2 = (V, E_2$

and $G = (V, E_1 \cup E_2)$, where $E_1 \cap E_2 = \varnothing$

And now it is not so trivial.

Comment: When you posted your question and before it was edited, it was not clear to me how you meant it exactly. If the vertex sets are the same and you define the union $G$ as above, then if $F_{G_1}$ and $F_{G_2}$ are spanning forests of $G_1$ and $G_2$ respectively, they both are spanning forests of $G$ as well! Clearly they span $G$ (since $G$ contains the same vertices as $G_1$ and $G_2$), and as forests they have no circles.